# Pass form object value to static method

Tags: c#, forms, object, static-methods

I need to take a form object value and pass it into a static method:

```
 public void SetCalendarStartSafe(DateTime startDateSafe)
 {
     startDateSafe = calendarStart.Value;
 }   

 private static DataTable GetData()
 {
     frmMain frm = new frmMain();
     DateTime startDate = new frmMain();
     frm.SetCalendarStartSafe(startDate);
 }
```

However I keep getting today's current date whenever I try this approach, even if the specified calendar date on the form is different. How can I can the user-specified calendar date from the original frmMain object?  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Is this C#? If you tag your question at least with the name of the language you use it will be easier to find and answer ;)

Comment: Write code that some odds of compiling, this is not close by a mile.

Comment: `DateTime startDate = new frmMain()`? Is startDate a DateTime or is it a frmMain? Maybe I'm reading your code wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you will be calling GetData() from somewhere in the code which is non-static? like for example from some event in the Form.. in that event pass the parameter to the static method GetData(DateTime..)

Comment: GetNumericTimeSeries():                                                 private static NumericTimeSeries GetNumericTimeSeries()
    {
      NumericTimeSeries numTimeSeries = new NumericTimeSeries();
      DataTable dTable = Getata();

      foreach (DataRow dr in dTable.AsEnumerable())
      {
        numTimeSeries.Points.Add(), System.Double.Parse(dr.ItemArray[8].ToString()), String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dr.ItemArray[2]), false));
      }
      return numTimeSeries;
    }

Comment: ?? Why not Pass the parameter to static function. and if u want to access instantiated objects from static function then better pass the parameter of object type to your static function. for example the whole form object itself.. (not a good way though)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SetCalendarStartSafe(DateTime startDateSafe)
{
    // wrong:
    // startDateSafe = calendarStart.Value;
    // right:
    calendarStart.Value = startDateSafe;
}
```

There, just swap those two around. The destination of the assignment is on the left.

Comment: Tried that suggested approach, but the calendarStart.Value is somehow getting reset to the the current date/time (if you look at the value during debug). Additionally, I get an error message that reads:
"Error loading chart: Value of '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'."